# How do I target a nested input that has no id attribute using Cypress?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, cypress, end-to-end

I am writing a Cypress test for a React project. I need to be able to target an `<input>` nested inside of a `<label>` so I can type into that input field. The `<input>`s have no class ids.

Here is my HTML.

```
    <label class="Input">
        <div class="label">LABEL TEXT</div>
        <input type="text">
    </label>
```

I have numerous inputs in the same form with the exact HTML shown above. They only differ by the text in the `<div>` (i.e. LABEL TEXT).

The reason that I am surrounding the `<input>` in a label tag is that I want the user to be able to target the input by clicking anywhere surrounding the label text OR the input. Adding a class to the inputs doesn't make sense for our code-base just for the sake of Cypress testing. I cannot use pseudo selectors such as :first `cy.get('input[type="text"]:first')` because I don't want my tests to break if I add additional inputs to the form.

I have tried the following, but it tries to type into the label instead of the input.

```
  cy.contains('LABEL TEXT')
      .click()
      .type('test')
```

Even though it puts focus on the  in the Cypress test runner, it still tries to type into the `<div>` instead of the focused input.

As I am very new to Cypress and assertions, I am left scratching my head. I'm interested in a solution (if possible) that doesn't involve adding classes to my inputs just for the sake of Cypress testing. I'm hoping this is just a shortcoming in my CSS, Cypress, or assertion knowledge.

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've just reproduced your exact same scenario of having several identical labels with just the inner div's texts being different. **Answer of Miguel Carvajal was close but needed some tweaking.** Following code worked properly:

```js
cy.get("div[class='label']").contains("LABEL TEXT2").parent().within(() => {
   cy.get("input[type='text']").type("StackOverflowHelp")
})
```

Tested on following HTML:

```html
<label class="Input">
  <div class="label">LABEL TEXT1</div>
  <input type="text">
</label>
<label class="Input">
  <div class="label">LABEL TEXT2</div>
  <input type="text">
</label>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think something like

```
cy.getByText("label text").parent().within(() => {

   cy.get('input') // this yields the input
})
```

will work.

I recommend you to check out https://github.com/testing-library/cypress-testing-library for some neat selectors

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to get some more precision!

Try:

```js
cy.get('.Input > input') // selects an <input> tag that is a direct
                         // descendant of a "Input" class
.click()
.type('test')
```

---

You can also use CSS selectors to select the `n`th element in the DOM that matches a selector:

```js
cy.get('.Input:nth-child(2) > input') // selects all <input> tags that
                                      // are direct children of the
                                      // second "Input"-class element
                                      // in any containing element
.click()
.type('test')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have numerous inputs in the form ALL with the same HTML structure shown in my example. They only differ by the contents of the <div>; the text "LABEL TEXT". Therefore, Cypress with throw an error because it will not result in a single element targeted in the DOM. I'll clarify this in my question. Thanks.

Comment: You can use CSS selectors to select the nth element in the DOM. :) I'll add it to my answer.